# Keep footer bottom of the Page

Tags: html, css

My HTML code is like below

[image]

Some of my CSS code is like below

```
.content {
  min-height: 58vh; 
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px; 
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #a0a6ad;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.footer-Content {
  padding-top: 36px;
}
```

I would like to make the footer responsive. So that when I decrease screen size it will stay at the bottom of the page.

[image]

If content is larger that page and I use below code then footer is fixed not scrolling with the page.

```
footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Actually I need a footer which will stay at the bottom of the page if screen size is increase or decrease and it will scroll with the page if the content is larger than the screen size.

Comment: Can u post your HTML code instead of images?

Comment: check this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_footer

Comment: Post HTML Please

Comment: Thanks @jsduniya. I need footer will move when scroll in this situation.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zicU9.png